# Import esm module or npm package as static javascript file

Tags: javascript, npm-install, transpiler

I am interested in the inclusion of this project :
https://github.com/jarvelov/vue-form-json-schema
The instruction explain how to instal it as npm package or esm module, but in my scenario i need to save a static javascript file (from a specific version) inside the project and use that file.

How can i downlaod the source form npm (or esm) and transpile it to a single js file?

Comment: Npm packages *are* static Javascript files, and that has nothing to do with esm modules. What's your question? It's not clear what you're asking here. Or why.

Comment: @JaredSmith sorry probably i have missphrased my question (english is not my mother tongue). I have two option epm or npm to incorporate the files of the project. I don't have the tool for use both the option. So i am wondering how to download source anyway and minify all js files in a single file i can use in my project (web application using Asp.Net, so the js shuld work on client side)

Comment: Let me try again. Your question is conflating *installing a package through npm* with *importing files in different module formats in your project*. Those are two *very different* things, and you yourself seem to be confused about which one you need help with. Your comment just now added a *third* very different thing, which is bundling a bunch of Javascript files into a single file which is it's own topic.

Comment: Yes i am not familiar with this way of include javascript files and related dependencies (i usually use nuget), for that reason i am a bit confused. My goal is to include all javascript i need into my project (Asp.Net web app) so i can use the functionality it provide. I don't know how to proceede with npm, nor the other way (that seems also to have limited browser support). So i am wondering how to download (from npm or esm cdn) the files i need (with all dependency) so i can include in my project. Thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do that, that's why we have npm. And again, you seem to think esm is a thing like npm, which it isn't. You need to create an npm project, install the dependencies (and their [transitive] dependencies, which is why you don't want to do it by hand) with npm, and bundle your Javascript with a bundler like webpack or rollup. You are going to actually have to learn Javascript in order to use Javascript. You're confused by the documentation because it assumes you already know all of that. I recommend googling for and then working through a good tutorial.

Comment: @JaredSmith is not clear to me why you assume i don't know javascript. I don't know how to import dependecies with those tool, if i have a nuget option i have not such problem (for example i installed vue through nuget).

Comment: "is not clear to me why you assume i don't know javascript" you don't understand the difference between Javascript module formats, or even between a module format and a *package manager*. You don't appear to know how Javascript projects are typically built and managed. Etc. etc. And that's *fine*. It's totally fine to not know it, you're not a professional Javascript developer. But the problem (that I seem to be struggling to communicate) is that you can't do what you're trying to do without learning the basics of modern Javascript development. It's not as simple as just downloading some files

Comment: Well, i expected that npm is a simple package manager, but now i just started digging into UMD and seems a complete different concept. That said you are right, i don't know those technology and i have many missconception about those instrument. But let me say, one thing are those instrument one other thin is javascript language (seems to me like to say that someone doesn't knwo math because don't know mathlab).